# Why I cant access pages of my Classic ASP site?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I am setting up a classic ASP site on my computer. I have installed all the necessary DLL's, configured the IIS and enabled ASP on my IIS. All the files of the website are in a folder named ClassicASP.This Folder is in wwwroot Folder of IIS.
Now my problem is that I am able to access the Login Page of my site. But when I enter credentials It doesnot redirects to the next page. Its gives 
"
**HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**
"

However the file is in the same folder. I can only access Login Page no other page is working it says Resource not Found.
Can some one help. I am new to ClassicASP.

Comment: You've tagged this question with c#, which has nothing to do with Classic ASP.  Classic ASP uses VBScript, (or occasionally JavaScript) as its server side language.

Comment: @stuartd: I wish there was a downvote facility for comments. Just saying.

Comment: @John: I am sorry. Its a mistake. removing it. Now please can we discuss the question rather then talking about tags?

Comment: Could you show some code.  Without that it's impossible to know why your redirect doesn't work.  I mentioned the c# tag because there loads of people on Stack Overflow who seem to  think "Classic ASP" means webforms

Comment: It's hard to say without code, but it seems to indicate that the url in the action attribute in your form does not exist. <form action="" />. Can you show us the ASP/HTML code for the form on your login page?

Comment: Can you get to the target url if you type it into your browser address bar ? If no then you have the file name wrong.